# Only a user connected to the VPN can access this webpage

Tags: centos, vpn, openvpn, http

I Have a VPS with CentOS I installed the VPN on it successfully. For Example, I have an HTTP Page like example.com/test.php . But the problem is I want to do only the users which are connected to VPN only access that page. Will any idea be appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this in many ways.

- Adjust your web server virtual host to be bound to a private IP that is only accessible to the VPN network
- Setup Firewall (netfilter) rules that only permit access from the VPN connected machines
- Setup ACLs within the web server configuration to only permit access.

Of course, if you are really paranoid, you might do all of the above.